# Understanding Kendo UI dialog with Angularjs scopes

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a [simple example of Kendo UI dialog with Angular](http://jsbin.com/upIMemAS/2/edit).

In the example there is a button which opens a Kendo modal dialog. Inside the dialog there is an input box and a close button.

I have two questions:

1. The ng-model of the input is "dialogOutput". I have a label outside of the dialog which is bided to this property but then the text inside the input is changed the label is not changed. I guess that the dialog has a different scope and that's why it behaves the way it is. What I don't understand is why when clicking the close button the scope of the close function is not the scope of the dialog? inside the close button I have `alert($scope.dialogOutput)` and it shows undefined.
2. What I want to do is when clicking the close button I want to "send" the data from the dialog to the outer scope, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot notation to share an object between multiple scopes.

[I have updated your jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aSEHiXUb/1/edit)

**EDIT**

When you write to a primitive type a new instance is created in your kendo directive scope not in the controller scope.

This kind of issue raises with primitive types. As explained [**here**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models.